# What is the maximum number of instructions in a tx?

Tags: transactions

How many instructions can i cram into a single TX? I'd like to make my code as efficient as possible, with as few as possible transactions

Answer (score 2):

Solana's networking stack uses a conservative MTU size of 1280 bytes which, after accounting for headers, leaves 1232 bytes for packet data like serialized transactions. Developers building applications on Solana must design their on-chain program interfaces within the above transaction size limit constraint.
[https://docs.solana.com/proposals/transactions-v2#:~:text=Solana's%20networking%20stack%20uses%20a,above%20transaction%20size%20limit%20constraint](https://docs.solana.com/proposals/transactions-v2#:%7E:text=Solana%27s%20networking%20stack%20uses%20a,above%20transaction%20size%20limit%20constraint).

You can send multi-transaction with a wallet sign. The code is existed in Metaplex.